# How can I import type-definitions from a typeshed stub-file?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function that abstracts away authentication logic and can be either based on SHA or MD5. Apart from the hash-implementation, the rest of the code is identical. The core part looks like this:

```
def hasher(hash_impl, arg1, arg1):
    # do stuff with arg1 and arg2
    hash = hash_impl(arg1)
    return hash.digest()

from hashlib import md5
hasher(md5, b"foo", b"bar")
```

The questions I have is about type-hinting.

The implementations in `hashlib` use [a stub-file](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/569fcea637023b3df2fe45c6f08c26037bfa6a74/stdlib/hashlib.pyi#L5) for typing.

How can I type-hint the above function with that `_Hash` object?

```
from ? import _Hash  # <-- How can I access _Hash?
from hashlib import md5, sha

def hasher(hash_impl: _Hash, arg1: bytes, args: bytes) -> bytes:
    ... as above ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried creating a little function stub for the type checker, which seems to do what you want:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, overload
from hashlib import md5

if TYPE_CHECKING:
  from hashlib import _Hash

  @overload
  def hasher(hash_impl: _Hash, arg1: bytes, args: bytes) -> bytes: ...

def hasher(hash_impl, arg1, args):
    # do stuff with arg1 and arg2
    hash = hash_impl(arg1)
    return hash.digest()

print(hasher(md5, b"foo", b"bar"))
```

Using that import outside of `if TYPE_CHECKING` will result in an import error though!

Also, wouldn't a callable type be more appropriate? I simply copied the type definition of `md5` from the stub-file. (It also takes an optional bool, you don't pass one to the function so I ignored it for now).
This way, `hash` will be type `_Hash` after the `hash_impl` returns:

```py
from typing import Callable, TYPE_CHECKING, overload
from hashlib import md5

if TYPE_CHECKING:
  from hashlib import _Hash
  from _typeshed import ReadableBuffer

  @overload
  def hasher(hash_impl: Callable[[ReadableBuffer], _Hash], arg1: bytes, args: bytes) -> bytes: ...

def hasher(hash_impl, arg1, args):
    # do stuff with arg1 and arg2
    hash = hash_impl(arg1)
    return hash.digest()

print(hasher(md5, b"foo", b"bar"))
```

Hope any of this helps!

Comment: Tried this solution, but mypy complains with `error: Single overload definition, multiple required`

Comment: hm, that doesnt happen on my machine. The actual function implementation cannot have any type hinting. Did you add any by chance?

Comment: Nope. My case is almost identical, just that my function has no arguments, and I'm just annotating the return type (`psycopg2.connection`)

Comment: Could you paste the code in a new question and link it here?

Comment: Here it is! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74534284/anotate-return-type-with-psycopg2-type-stub